# how to properly remove these cable connectors

Tags: electrical, cables

Do I twist or pull them off

I tried by hand and wasnt getting anywhere so next step is going to be the pliers and i just want to make sure im not breaking it.

[image]

Comment: It's a crimp connector that's meant to be permanent, meaning it's not intended to come off easily. You will need to cut it off.

Comment: you should move your comment to the answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some (not all, depends on the crimp style) cases you can use pliers (or locking pliers such as vise-grip) to squeeze an "oval" or "flattened" crimp on the long axis, and that will open the hole enough that you can slip the wires out. If not, yes, you have to cut them off, as per the comment that @Steve should make into an answer.

If that does work, you still should plan on new connectors for whatever new wiring work you are doing, as "recrimping" used connectors is not very reliable.

Comment: Ehh. Your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

These are single-use crimps and you surely will destroy it. I understand not wanting to waste any wire length, but prying them apart is a hard fight... not worth fooling around with, just cut them.

But look closely at where the metal part of the  crimp actually is, and cut *just* below it, right through the plastic and all.  That way you're only losing 3/8" or so.

Replace with wire-nuts or stab-and-lever splices.

Comment: i was able to easily remove them using Ecnerwal's technique!  but thank you.  I did of course buy more, i didnt put the used ones back on

Comment: @owengerig I wouldn't use crimps at all.  I'm not a fan of the special tool and how they're very particular about wire placement and fastening strength and method.   If in EU I would use their lovely terminal blocks, if in North America, lever Wagos or wire nuts.